# How to get duration of Youtube video without playing the video in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, video, youtube

I am a newbie in ReactJS and I badly need some help.

So I have a video catalog that only shows the thumbnails of the videos with label and overlay duration. Before I was using React-Player by Pete Cook but I don't want that my video player has share, like and watch later buttons so I decided to not use it and use video-player instead. I just use Image tag for showing thumbnail and I will just pass the Youtube link to the video player if the image is clicked.

Now my problem is that I am having a hard time in getting the video duration. When I was still using React-Player, I can get it after clicking play button (not the result that I want but at least I was able to get the duration). Any solution for this? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you're providing a Youtube URL to the video-player library's `Player` Component which clearly doesn't support it as mentioned [here](https://github.com/video-react/video-react/issues/21#issuecomment-280989819).

I even tried it you'll get no duration value nor the video will be played.
However, if you changed your Youtube link to for example this one https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4

You'll find that everything is working perfectly and you can get the `duration` state from the Player's states without even playing the video.

```
const { player } = this.player.getState();
console.log(player.duration);
```

I added these two lines to the a method called `changeSource` mentioned [here](https://video-react.js.org/components/player/) under Examples title.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response but I am not using <video> tag but just an <image> tag. What I am using in playing the video is the video-player library which you can read it here https://video-react.js.org/.